# PATH environment for administrator variable and user variable

Tags: python, path, environment-variables

My company administrator has installed python on my company pc, but we needed to set up `PATH`environment variable to be able to run Python without showing full path. When we added it, then it appears that it works (finds path) only if terminal is run with Administrator rights. I do not have Administrator rights, when I run it as regular user it gives back error message `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`How to setup `PATH` variable to be able to run e.g. Python without showing full path. To add here - also pandas library does not compiles - it cannot find path and gives back error message. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/121664-set-new-user-system-environment-variables-windows.html

You can set the User Environment Variables.

Comment: if you use windows operating system you can refer to this answer
[add path to environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/13754477)